# Merge multiple tracklogs or route points to one polyline

Tags: postgis, polyline-creation, generalization, tracking, combine

I'm having a similar case like the one posted [Tracklogs to single line OR several lines to one line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6902/tracklogs-to-single-line-or-several-lines-to-one-line).

However what differs in my question here is that I want to display the merged or common shared route points as a single polyline on the openstreet map using leaflet.js.

Is there any way to draw only single lines for the routes driven wile maintaining the count of inline routes?

What I have is the coordinates of each trip in my postgres database and I'm having django framework for handling the webserver. What I want to achieve is to display all the trips on the openstreet map while avoiding the overlapping of multiple routes. But I still wish to display the count of routes sharing the common route segment.

Comment: I suggest to use map matching. Valhallas free to use public API can be used.

Comment: @TimothyDalton thanks, it would be great if you could tell me something bit more about this.